How does this proof of Gauss’ law generalize from $1$ to $n$ charges?
I am having trouble seeing how the proof of Gauss’ law for one charge generalizes to hold for multiple charges in Griffiths’ introduction to electrodynamics.
Gauss’ law is proved for one charge (for spherical surfaces) in the following way: let $q$ be a point charge at the origin. Then the flux of $\mathbf{E}$ through a spherical surface of radius $r$ is $$\oint \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{a} =  \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \left( \frac{q}{r^2} \right)\mathbf{\hat{r}} \cdot \left(r^2\text{sin}\theta d\theta d\phi\right)\mathbf{\hat{r}}$$
which evaluates to $\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$.
Then if you have multiple charges, the total field is the vector sum of all the individual fields, and so applying the previous integral the flux through a surface that encloses all the charges is $$\oint \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{a} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \oint \mathbf{E_i} \cdot d\mathbf{a} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n q_i \frac{1}{\epsilon_0}.$$
Here is my problem. I think the integral in the first case takes the form it does, where you can let the unit separation vector $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ be the unit vector of the infinitesimal surface area, because the unit vector in the direction from the point charge at the origin to some point on the spherical surface is in the same direction as the normal vector on the surface at that point. Then $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ disappears from the integrand because for any vector $\mathbf{v}$, $a\mathbf{v} \cdot b\mathbf{v} = ab|\mathbf{v}|^2$, and our integrand is of this form with $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ and $|\mathbf{\hat{r}}| = 1$. However, I do not see how this reasoning holds in the case of multiple point charges. Because if you have multiple charges, most if not all of them are going to be off of the origin, and the separation vector $\mathbf{r}$ from any charge off the origin $q’$ to an arbitrary point on the surface of the sphere will not be in the same direction as the normal vector at that point on the surface. Then in many if not every $ \oint \mathbf{E}_i \cdot d\mathbf{a}$ you cannot let the unit normal vector to the surface be $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$, which seems to complicate the integral significantly and prevent the integral in the first case from applying.
Am I missing something?

Point charges can be arbitrarily close together in comparison to the distance to the spherical surface...have you considered what the separation vector looks like when assuming the displacement from the origin is arbitrarily small compared to the radius of the sphere?

@Triatticus I see your point but I think the ultimate goal here is to prove Guass’ law for situations where that assumption doesn’t necessarily hold

I am reviewing the textbook and now I’m not sure if Griffiths actually thinks the proof of the more general version is even connected to the proof of the simpler version; the latter relaxes the assumption of a spherical surface and may rely more on a field lines argument than a mathematical argument to assert that the flux through a surface due to one charge is $\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$

First verify that Gauss’s law also holds for charges that are off-center. Note that even after you figure out this generalization, you still wouldn’t have proved the full Gauss’ law which applies for ALL closed surfaces, not just spherical ones.

@Joa sure but if it works when they are very close together, expanding them out cannot change the answer as the flux lines still go through the same surface. However as noted proving for a sphere isn't general enough as is.....it's just easier to use.

I don't see a problem with the charges being off center. He is not using a gaussian surface in which E is a constant. He is not attempting to calculate the electric field, but rather the total flux by adding the individual ones, which are the integrals of these fields, and each charge contributes its own field and flux, each flux being $q_i/ϵ_0$.

But I don’t see how it has been proved mathematically that the flux due to each charge is $q/ \epsilon_0$ when the charge is a non-negligible distance from the origin

That is gauss theorem, it doesn't involve a surface of any particular shape just a closed one, the electric field does not need to be normal to or constant across the surface. The integral is always $q/ \epsilon_0$. Do not get confused with the fact that you can use gauss theorem to easily calculate electric fields for very specific very symmetric configurations. But here you are not using the theorem to calculate E, you are just using the theorem and the fact that electric fields are linear (the ones from different sources just add to each other at every point, and thus the fluxes too)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law#Integral_form

I believe OP is looking for a proof of Gauss' law, and one that invokes Gauss' law is rather unsatisfoactory I'd say?

Since the main issue is that the charges may be off-centre, consider the case of a single point charge $q$ inside a sphere $S_1$ and not necessarily at the centre. Enclose the point charge in a smaller sphere $S_2$ contained in $S_1$ but this time with the $q$ at the centre of $S_2$.

Now, apply the divergence theorem to the region $R$ between $S_1$ and $S_2$ (noting that the normal to the one of the bounding surfaces $S_2$ points toward the center of $S_2$ instead of radially outward)
$$\int\limits_{R} d^3x\nabla\cdot \vec{E}= \oint_{S_1} \vec{E}\cdot \hat{n}_1 dA+\oint_{S_2} \vec{E}\cdot (-\hat{n}_2) dA$$
The left-hand side of the equation vanishes because $\nabla\cdot \vec{E}=0$ for our point charge in the region $R$. So we conclude
$$\oint_{S_1}\vec{E}\cdot \hat{n}_1 dA=\oint_{S_2}\vec{E}\cdot \hat{n}_2 dA\,\,,$$
that is, the Electric flux through $S_1$ (where $q$ is off-centre) is exactly the same as the flux through the sphere $S_2$ (here q is at the centre and you've already shown how to take the integral).
Also note that $S_1$ need not be a sphere for this argument to hold. Have a look at Stewart's calculus textbook where this is discussed in a little more detail, but I think I've given the gist.
